# Publisher-Subscriber architecture with central registry

Tags: architecture, c++, c, networking, pubsub

## Problem description

Publisher-Subscriber architecture with a central registry where agents can either promote their capabilities or search for a given capability.

The project must be developed with C/C++. A GUI used to compose a chain of agents is a nice-to-have (not necessarily C or C++).

## Current state of my thinking

- Set up the Publisher-Subscriber in place using [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/)
- The central registry (or notice-board) role is only to connect agents between them using sockets
- Data serialization is performed either with [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) or [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

## Questions

It's the first time I'm asked to develop a Publisher/Subscriber architecture and I've never used the libraries I listed above.

Does my approach look good to you?

Answer (score 1):

First, your idea sound fine to me.

I suggest, you have a look at different registries.

I also suggest looking at specific ideas, such as that from elixir: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Registry.html (see down the page for pub/sub)

Consider (if you use topics) defining a naming scheme/tree for the published messages.